# Why does the Convention badge apply on main sites?

Tags: support, badges, meta

I just earned the Convention badge over on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/). Fine, great, but here's a question: why is it a main-site badge not a meta-badge? I have ended up with 2 silver badges on main and none on meta, yet to me this badge would seem to apply more to my meta activity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the point of the badge is to **advertise Meta** and encourage users to participate there. If the badge only existed on Meta, then there would be nothing on the main site directing users to go there and participate. It'd be more of a "hey now that you found your way here, we'll give you a badge for participating" which is kind of pointless since they can already get other badges on Meta for simply participating on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess here. People who are active on main won't see your meta badges. This way, there's a badge to encourage meta participation, which adds to your main site badge count...

You get separate badges for your high scoring meta posts.